# How does a ram-air parachute move forward?

Tags: drag, aerodynamics, aircraft

I'm trying to understand the "physics" behind the flight of a ram air parachute,

Do you know / how could I know, whether the main parameter that makes a [ram-air parachute](https://www.google.com/search?q=ram+air+parachute&tbm=isch) move forward is:

1. Assuming that the parachute has a negative angle of attack, the air that is redirected to the rear of the canopy, when the parachute falls into the air
2. The lift due to the airfoil shape whose direction is mainly upwards, but also a little towards the front of the wing

Then, in my understanding, if the ram-air parachute canopy is heavier wing loaded, it should fall vertically a bit faster because its terminal speed will be higher, but:

1. Will its horizontal speed also increase?
2. Will it increase faster than the vertical speed or slower?
3. Is there so a point where the ratio of horizontal speed to vertical speed would be the highest and therefore the glide ratio would be the highest?

Comment: Read [*this*](https://www.av8n.com/how/). It's a bit long but packed with understanding. A ram-air parachute is like any other wing.